Prove: Neighbourhood of Spanning Tree is exact
In my lecture the neighbourhood of a spanning tree f is defined as: N(f) = {g element of F | g can be obtained from f as follows: Add an edge to the tree f, producing a cycle, then delete any edge from the cycle}. Where F is the set of feasible solutions.
In the lecture it was said that this neighbourhood is exact, meaning that every local optimum with respect to the neighbourhood is a global optimum. In other words: If f is a local optimum regarding N(f), then f is a minimum spanning tree.
However, there was no proof given. How can one prove, that the neighbourhood of MST is indeed exact? I think, it might have something to do with the cut property...
Thank you for your help!! <3

Please explain what you mean by feasible, optimum etc. You haven't defined any optimization problem!

You're right. Let me add some details: The overall topic is minimum spanning trees. The optimization problem is defined as follows: (F, c) with F being the set of feasible solutions, in this case the set of all possible spanning trees of that graph and c being the cost function, in this case the sum of the edge's weights in a spanning tree. A local optimum is a spanning tree that has the smallest cost compared to all other spanning trees in its neighbourhood. The statement to prove is: Every local optimum is a global optimum.
